# Cannot insert data in Mysql SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8, and when I try to insert data into the MySQL database, I encounter an error as shown in the image. How can I fix this issue? Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5KcV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rgwd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOLps.png)

Hello, I am using Laravel 8, and when I try to insert data into the MySQL database, I encounter an error as shown in the image. How can I fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: It means table not exist in the database did you run ```php artisan migrate```?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Error which is mentioned in your screenshots is coming because of your validation of `'tendanhmuc'=>'required|unique:tendanhmuc|max:255'`

laravel unique validation is searching for table **tendanhmuc** in your database. But it does not exist.

**Solution:** Replace your validation rule for tendanhmuc field with below code.

```
'tendanhmuc'=>'required|unique:danhmuc,tendanhmuc|max:255'
```

There are many syntax of laravel to use unique validation. Read more about [laravel unique validation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique).

Comment: I followed your instructions and successfully added the database. Thanks you